# ContainerView update on model change

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to render a component dynamically based on the property of an object in the current model. The model is changing yet the container view only updates once. What do i need to do to get this to work properly?

http://jsbin.com/iHIveti/4/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, is this what you are looking for: http://jsbin.com/iHIveti/11/edit ?

Basically what I've changed is your `observer` to this:

```
  ...
  viewChanged:function(){
    console.log("HERE");
  }.observes('model.@each')
  ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While I tried to illustrate my issue in the jsbin, I don't think it totally encapsulated what I was trying to do. I was trying to perform a task when the model changed. Everything I was doing was happening too late in the process and therefor wasn't working.

That being said, your solution did the trick! I was able to perform the action at the appropriate time, therefore solving my issue. Thanks!